# Capture and evaluate argument constraint "*_"

Tags: mocking, spock

Spock has this nice syntax to check whether a method with a certain name was called, ignoring the number of arguments:

```
1 * subscriber.receive(*_) // any argument list (including the empty argument list)
```

Is it possible to capture the argument list in an `Object[]` array and do assertions on it?

Something like this:

```
1 * subscriber.receive(*args)
args.size() < 2 || args.size() > 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax to check arguments as an array:

```
1 * subscriber.receive(*_) >> { assert it.size() < 1 || it.size() > 5 }
```

when an interaction closure is used, when it is called with an untyped argument, this argument take all the parameters as an array.

Comment: Great, I missed that. Thanks!